# EditorGrid dynamic/dependant Combo Box Editor Fields

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS, say you have a simple editorgrid with two columns, X and Y, both of which have a combo box as their editor.

How is is possible to make the values available in the second column's combo box (Y) depend on the selected value in the first column (X)?

So, depending on what is selected in X, the values available in Y change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to answer my question:

As the EditorGrid in question uses a `RowSelectionModel` (not a `CellSelectionModel`), I was able to add the below to the `beforeselect` event of the `editor` `combobox`:

```
Ext.getCmp('EDITORGRID').selModel.getSelected().set('colY','myvalue');
```

Having updated the relevant store as necessary, `myvalue` was simply set to the first record returned.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a store backing each combobox, you can use the store's `filter` or `filterBy` methods to narrow down the results of one combobox based on the other's current selection. You can call either filter function on the `'select'` or `'change'` events of the combobox. I've used this method successfully in the past, and it worked well for my needs. I had around 200 records per combobox, so I'm not sure how well this solution scales if you have a good deal records more than that.

Comment: Can you provide some code? When changing the value in the first combo box, how can I get the record which that the combo box sits in (the change event only returns the record for the combo box's store, not the master grid store) and then reference the adjacent column?

Comment: So I need to register the combo box being changed then find the grid record that combo box is altering (and not the record changed in the combo box itself), then use the grid record as a reference alter the next column for that record

Comment: I would use the select event because it passes in the record that was selected, which you can then filter on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example from [JoeKuan](http://joekuan.org/demos/dynamic_row_editor/)